# Reading repeated XML nodes in VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, nested

I have an XML string that I need to tear down and process. Sorry for what may be a simple problem, but I'm new to XML processing.

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<CCSMessage Type="4" Name="CustomerFetchResponse" Source="CoremaContextServer" Destination="WSA0205" UserID="LoyaltyBatch" IncludeLoyaltySummary="true" LimitLoyaltyTransactions="0" >
<Result>
    <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
</Result>
<Customer CustomerID="36240">
    <CustomerID CCSID="289521" TimeStamp="2010-10-01 12:13:53">36240
    </CustomerID>
    <LoyaltySummary HouseholdID="110000036242" LoyaltyStatus="2" TotalSpend="6419.80" TotalVisits="136">
        <LoyaltyIDs>
            <LoyaltyID ID="410000073094" RedeemFlag="true" DateIssued="2010-10-01">
            </LoyaltyID>
        </LoyaltyIDs>
        <OfferProgress>
            <OfferProgressTotals OfferID="1012" OfferType="P" OfferDescription="No Email Birthday Promotion for Dec" OptIn="Y">
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="1" Description="Earned">
                    <LifetimeValue>0</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="2" Description="Last Reward">
                    <LifetimeValue>0</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="3" Description="Redeemed">
                    <LifetimeValue>0</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="4" Description="Total 4">
                    <LifetimeValue>0.00</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <EligibleDate>11/24/2014</EligibleDate>
                <ExpirationDate>12/31/2014</ExpirationDate>
                <TotalUsage>-2147483648</TotalUsage>
                <ExpiringAwards>
                    <ExpiringAward OfferID="1112" OfferDescription="null">
                        <PointsEarned>1</PointsEarned>
                        <PointsRedeemed>1</PointsRedeemed>
                        <PointsExpired>0</PointsExpired>
                        <AwardExpiryDate>1900-01-01</AwardExpiryDate>
                    </ExpiringAward>
                </ExpiringAwards>
            </OfferProgressTotals>
            <OfferProgressTotals OfferID="2012" OfferType="P" OfferDescription="Email Birthday Coupon for Dec" OptIn="N">
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="1" Description="Earned">
                    <LifetimeValue>0</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="2" Description="Last Reward">
                    <LifetimeValue>0</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="3" Description="Redeemed">
                    <LifetimeValue>0</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="4" Description="Total 4">
                    <LifetimeValue>0.00</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <EligibleDate>12/02/2014</EligibleDate>
                <ExpirationDate>12/31/2014</ExpirationDate>
                <TotalUsage>-2147483648</TotalUsage>
                <ExpiringAwards>
                </ExpiringAwards>
            </OfferProgressTotals>
            <OfferProgressTotals OfferID="4008" OfferType="P" OfferDescription="Email Anniversary Coupon for Aug" OptIn="N">
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="1" Description="Earned">
                    <LifetimeValue>0</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="2" Description="Last Reward">
                    <LifetimeValue>0</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="3" Description="Redeemed">
                    <LifetimeValue>0</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="4" Description="Total 4">
                    <LifetimeValue>0.00</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <EligibleDate>08/01/2014</EligibleDate>
                <ExpirationDate>08/31/2014</ExpirationDate>
                <TotalUsage>-2147483648</TotalUsage>
                <ExpiringAwards>
                </ExpiringAwards>
            </OfferProgressTotals>
            <OfferProgressTotals OfferID="9001" OfferType="P" OfferDescription="Birthday promotion" OptIn="Y">
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="1" Description="Earned">
                    <LifetimeValue>1</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="2" Description="Last Reward">
                    <LifetimeValue>0</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="3" Description="Redeemed">
                    <LifetimeValue>0</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="4" Description="Total 4">
                    <LifetimeValue>0.00</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <EligibleDate>01/01/2010</EligibleDate>
                <ExpirationDate>12/31/2100</ExpirationDate>
                <TotalUsage>-2147483648</TotalUsage>
                <ExpiringAwards>
                    <ExpiringAward OfferID="9002" OfferDescription="null">
                        <PointsEarned>1</PointsEarned>
                        <PointsRedeemed>0</PointsRedeemed>
                        <PointsExpired>0</PointsExpired>
                        <AwardExpiryDate>1900-01-01</AwardExpiryDate>
                    </ExpiringAward>
                    <ExpiringAward OfferID="9002" OfferDescription="null">
                        <PointsEarned>1</PointsEarned>
                        <PointsRedeemed>0</PointsRedeemed>
                        <PointsExpired>0</PointsExpired>
                        <AwardExpiryDate>2012-01-12</AwardExpiryDate>
                    </ExpiringAward>
                </ExpiringAwards>
            </OfferProgressTotals>
            <OfferProgressTotals OfferID="9011" OfferType="P" OfferDescription="Pharmacy promotion" OptIn="Y">
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="1" Description="Earned">
                    <LifetimeValue>157</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="2" Description="Last Reward">
                    <LifetimeValue>0</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="3" Description="Redeemed">
                    <LifetimeValue>150</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="4" Description="Total 4">
                    <LifetimeValue>0.00</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <EligibleDate>01/01/2010</EligibleDate>
                <ExpirationDate>12/31/2100</ExpirationDate>
                <TotalUsage>-2147483648</TotalUsage>
                <ExpiringAwards>
                    <ExpiringAward OfferID="9012" OfferDescription="null">
                        <PointsEarned>15</PointsEarned>
                        <PointsRedeemed>15</PointsRedeemed>
                        <PointsExpired>0</PointsExpired>
                        <AwardExpiryDate>1900-01-01</AwardExpiryDate>
                    </ExpiringAward>
                </ExpiringAwards>
            </OfferProgressTotals>
            <OfferProgressTotals OfferID="9021" OfferType="P" OfferDescription="2013 - 10 for 300" OptIn="N">
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="1" Description="Earned">
                    <LifetimeValue>244523</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="2" Description="Last Reward">
                    <LifetimeValue>0</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="3" Description="Redeemed">
                    <LifetimeValue>240000</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="4" Description="Total 4">
                    <LifetimeValue>0.00</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <EligibleDate>01/02/2012</EligibleDate>
                <ExpirationDate>12/31/2099</ExpirationDate>
                <TotalUsage>-2147483648</TotalUsage>
                <ExpiringAwards>
                    <ExpiringAward OfferID="9022" OfferDescription="">
                        <PointsEarned>8</PointsEarned>
                        <PointsRedeemed>7</PointsRedeemed>
                        <PointsExpired>0</PointsExpired>
                        <AwardExpiryDate>1900-01-01</AwardExpiryDate>
                    </ExpiringAward>
                </ExpiringAwards>
            </OfferProgressTotals>
            <OfferProgressTotals OfferID="9031" OfferType="P" OfferDescription="2014 - 10 for 300" OptIn="N">
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="1" Description="Earned">
                    <LifetimeValue>33420</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="2" Description="Last Reward">
                    <LifetimeValue>0</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="3" Description="Redeemed">
                    <LifetimeValue>30000</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="4" Description="Total 4">
                    <LifetimeValue>0.00</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <EligibleDate>01/02/2012</EligibleDate>
                <ExpirationDate>12/31/2099</ExpirationDate>
                <TotalUsage>-2147483648</TotalUsage>
                <ExpiringAwards>
                    <ExpiringAward OfferID="9032" OfferDescription="null">
                        <PointsEarned>0</PointsEarned>
                        <PointsRedeemed>0</PointsRedeemed>
                        <PointsExpired>0</PointsExpired>
                        <AwardExpiryDate>1900-01-01</AwardExpiryDate>
                    </ExpiringAward>
                    <ExpiringAward OfferID="9032" OfferDescription="null">
                        <PointsEarned>1</PointsEarned>
                        <PointsRedeemed>0</PointsRedeemed>
                        <PointsExpired>0</PointsExpired>
                        <AwardExpiryDate>2014-05-29</AwardExpiryDate>
                    </ExpiringAward>
                </ExpiringAwards>
            </OfferProgressTotals>
            <OfferProgressTotals OfferID="15" OfferType="T" OfferDescription="Track email reminders" OptIn="N">
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="1" Description="Purchased">
                    <LifetimeValue>2</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="2" Description="Awarded">
                    <LifetimeValue>2</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="3" Description="Total 3">
                    <LifetimeValue>0.00</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <OfferProgressTotal ID="4" Description="Total 4">
                    <LifetimeValue>0.00</LifetimeValue>
                </OfferProgressTotal>
                <EligibleDate></EligibleDate>
                <ExpirationDate></ExpirationDate>
                <TotalUsage>-2147483648</TotalUsage>
            </OfferProgressTotals>
        </OfferProgress>
    </LoyaltySummary>
</Customer>
```

I can get to the  level just fine with this code:

```
xDocument.LoadXml(XMLResponse)
doc = XElement.Parse(XMLResponse)
For Each offer As XElement In doc.Descendants("OfferProgressTotals")
    If offer.HasAttributes Then
        TempOfferID = offer.Attribute("OfferID").Value
    End If
    If TempOfferID = _OneAct._Program Then
        If offer.HasElements Then
            Console.WriteLine("Offer ID : " + offer.Attribute("OfferID").Value)
            Console.WriteLine("Eligible Date : " + offer.Element("EligibleDate").Value)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

As you can see in the XML, there are repeated  nodes, but I only want to use the ones that are under the  where the OfferID matches what I am looking for. I have been searching for examples for days, and have not come up with anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `XMLReaders` (see link below). It should be easy to change the following to suite your needs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work as is. However your sample doesn't contain any repeating values for "OfferProgressTotals/OfferID"

If you need to match a pattern in the ID, it's stored as a string, so, you can use the available methods for String to find matches at the beginning of the string(.StartsWith), the end of the string(.EndsWith) or any substring inside the string(.Contains).

If you'd like something more concise you could use LINQ.  Something like this:

```
    Dim searchstr as String = "90"
    doc.Descendants("OfferProgressTotals") _
        .Where(Function(x) x.HasAttributes) _
        .Where(Function(x) x.Attribute("OfferID").Value.StartsWith(searchstr)) _
        .ToList _
        .ForEach(Sub(x) Console.WriteLine("Offer ID : " + x.Attribute("OfferID").Value & vbNewLine & "Eligible Date : " + x.Element("EligibleDate").Value))
```

This will output the information for every OfferID that starts with "90".

If you want info from the child nodes something like this should work:

```
Dim searchstr = "9001"
doc.Descendants("OfferProgressTotals") _
    .Where(Function(x) x.HasAttributes) _
    .Where(Function(x) x.Attribute("OfferID").Value = searchstr) _
    .First(Function(x)
                Console.WriteLine("Offer ID : {0}" & vbNewLine _
                                    & "Eligible Date : {1}" & vbNewLine, _
                                    x.Attribute("OfferID").Value, _
                                    x.Element("EligibleDate").Value)
                Return True
            End Function) _
    .Descendants("OfferProgressTotal") _
    .ToList _
    .ForEach(Sub(x)
                    Console.WriteLine("ID : {0}" & vbNewLine _
                                    & "Description : {1}" & vbNewLine _
                                    & "Lifetime Value : {2}" & vbNewLine, _
                                    x.Attribute("ID").Value, _
                                    x.Attribute("Description").Value, _
                                    x.Element("LifetimeValue").Value)
                End Sub)
```

This finds the parent node you're looking for and outputs the info you want, then it goes through each child node of "OfferProgressTotal" and outputs their info.